# How can I rewrite this as one linq statement?

Tags: linq

I really suck at LINQ statements, so if someone could help me find a way to consolidate these two statements, I would be forever grateful:

```
public IList<SomeType> getSomeTypes(string id){
        string itemName = (from item in _itemcollection
                    where item.id.Equals(id)
                    select item.name).FirstOrDefault();
        return (from item in _itemcollection
                item.name == itemName
                select item)
               .ToList();
```

id is a unique id, and this is _itemcollection is an IQueryable.

The goal is to get the Name of the item that matches the id (which is unique), then find all the items that have the same name (of which there are many).

Comment: Is `id` unique, or could there be more than one item with the same id?

Comment: Also, is _itemCollection an in memory collection or an IQueryable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public IList<SomeType> getSomeTypes(string id) {

  return (from item1 in _itemcollection
          join item2 in _itemcollection on item1.name equals item2.name
          where 
            item1.id.Equals(id)
          select item2).ToList();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I like using [**let**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383976.aspx) for these cases or just inlining

```
from item in _itemcollection
let match = _itemcollection.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id.Equals(id))
let itemName = match == null ? '' : match.name
where item.name == itemName 
select item
```